# Conventions for Distinguishing a Property when Describing Different Objects

Tags: math-mode, pseudocode, variable

I have several objects, in this case they are indexed sequences which are used in an algorithm written in pseudo-code and in mathematical expressions. For example, there is `$V$` and `$S$`, and there is a map `$V : \longrightarrow S$` or otherwise could be considered `$S$` is a property of `$V$` perhaps. And then there is a map `$V :\longrightarrow C$`, and a map `$S \longrightarrow C$`, and there is also a map `$V \longrightarrow V$` (which in this case is a representation of connected paths, where `$V$` are nodes.

I'm not finding a good choice of symbols to use to represent these objects in the pseudo-code. I also use subscripts already in this manner. `$i_v$` represents the index of object of `$v \in V$. $v_i$` represents the `$i^{th}$` element of `$V$`, and so forth for the other objects. So I'm not sure how I should say that the `$c$` property of `$v_i$`.

I like writing in terms of functions , e.g. `$C(v_i)$`. But sometimes I want to denote the whole array, e.g. which might be denoted like this? `$C( V ) = [ C( v_0 ), C( v_1 ), ..., C( v_n ) ]$`. Rather than `$C(V)$`, could I a superscript, like `$C^V$` or would that be odd?

Anyways, what are the conventions people use to represent these kinds of mappings?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You might want to use `$V \mapsto C$` and `$V \to C$` instead of spelling out `\longrightarrow` every time.